# Writing an IF statement in a dynamic dropdown select menu gives ERROR

Tags: php, html, select, dropdown

I want to write an IF statement for a dynamically generated dropdown menu, but I keep getting errors or it doesn't just work, what I am trying to do is compare two variables to see if they match from a data in the database

**$loma = "Asokoro";**

**$row['locales']** is from locality table in the database

$row['locales'] = "Asokoro";

$row['locales'] = "Dutse";

$row['locales'] = "Mari";

$row['locales'] = "Cook";

That means if `$loma` which is **Asokoro** matches `$row['locales']` = "Asokoro"; select it as the option menu

```
<select name="checkout_area_name" id="checkout_area_name" required>
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `locality` WHERE state_name = '$hi_state'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con, $query));
    $r = ' <option value="">Please Choose Locality</option>';
    ?>
    <?php
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
        ?>
        <?php $r = $r . '<option value="'.$loma.'" if ("'.$loma.' == '.$row["locales"].'") selected="selected" >'.$row['locales'].'</option>'; ?>
        <?php
    }
    echo $r;    
    ?>
</select>
```

I am trying to select the options menu that has `$loma` and `$row['locales']` matching but I keep getting errors or when I console.log, it does not produce the result i want.

Comment: php is server side. Once you can see your page, it's gone and is just html/javascript

Comment: @doVrine so is there no way to solve this problem, cause I really need it to show data to users that has been stored as a select option menu it works without PHP tag around it the other codes i do write this I mean <option value="Abuja" <?php if ($ira['state_name'] == 'Abuja') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>FCT/Abuja</option>

Comment: @dovrine all hands on deck would be appreciated

Comment: @dovrine Yes you have a point but I know its possible, I cant seem to just get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting php script as html markup, try changing your code to:

```
<select name="checkout_area_name" id="checkout_area_name" required>
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `locality` WHERE state_name = '$hi_state'"; $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con, $query)); $r = '
  <option value="">Please Choose Locality</option>'; ?>
  <?php
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
      $r = $r . '<option value="'.$loma.'" '.(($loma==$row["locales"])?'selected':'').'>'.$row['locales'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $r;    
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer really helped a lot, and also correcting me on my mistake.